# What happened with the manifest file of android?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, manifest

I have update **android studio** version 3.2.

After that, some gradle files are also converted with this type of encoding:

[image]

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do `undo` from the IDE

Comment: Click `File -> Settings -> Editor` and find `File Encodings` in your Android Studio; change it to `UTF-8`

Answer (score 0):

Add `systemProp.file.encoding=UTF-8` to `gradle.properties` to fix all encoding problems.